# How to customize AutoCompleteTextView dropdown on Android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I would like to know how, if it can be done, to customize the color of the dropdown from the `AutoCompleteTextView` when selected. I can customize everything else, but not the selected color ie - it stays the same.

In the `Activity`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, strings);
autoNewBird = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteBirdName);
autoNewBird.setAdapter(adap);
```

row.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/birdtext"
android:padding="5dip"  
android:background="@drawable/custom_spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/spinner_item" 
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:lines="1"/>
```

and the drawable custom_spinner.xml (in drawable folder)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/listback" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/listback" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/threebythree" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/threebythree" />              
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listback" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listback" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/listback" />
</selector>
```

This works for a spinner dropdown, but for an `AutoCompleteTextView`, when selected, it does not change color like the spinner dropdown.

Any help, or experience with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess I figured it out, or rather what I was doing wrong.
In a theme I put this:

```
<item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/custom_autocomplete</item>
```

and the style is(or relevant part):

```
<item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/custom_spinner</item>
```

and the custom_spinner is above.

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: This is the right solution. For more clarification, the second line should go in style defined like this: <style name="custom_autocomplete" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView"></style>. Hope that helps:)

Comment: Which layout are you using for the layout? I am doing like this aAdapterAutoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.auto_complete_text, suggest);
     autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapterAutoComplete);

Answer (score 5):

In xml, for AutoCompleteTextView

```
android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/some_drawable"
```

Comment: Only this worked for me.  Adding: <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/custom_spinner</item> to my autocomplete style class did not work as not all attributes work in the style file and instead have to be added in the autocomplete definition in the xml layout.